# Реализация паттерна Observer

Tags: java, observer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Publish publish = new Publish();

    /**
     * create a stream to read from the file and check what the line is - subscribe, unsubscribe or publish
     */
    try (BufferedReader bufIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sampleIn.txt"))) {
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        while((line = bufIn.readLine()) != null) {
            stringList.add(line);
        }
        for(String s : stringList) {
            String[] splitLine = s.split(",");
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitLine));
            if (splitLine[0].toLowerCase().equals("subscribe")) {
                publish.register(new PodcastSubscriber(splitLine[1], splitLine[2]));
            } else if (splitLine[0].toLowerCase().equals("unsubscribe")) {
                publish.unregister(new PodcastSubscriber(splitLine[1], splitLine[2]));
            } else if (splitLine[0].toLowerCase().equals("publish")) {
                publish.postMessage(new ChannelProgram(splitLine[1], splitLine[2], splitLine[3]));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Скорее всего `try-with-resources`

```
try (BufferedWriter bufOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))) {
    bufOut.write(stringBuilder.toString());
    bufOut.flush();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

закрывает `System.out` после выхода из блока, после чего `System.out` игнорирует все дальнейшие попытки в него писать. Проще всего убрать эту конструкцию и использовать `System.out.println` напрямую, либо создавать поток один раз в `main`, передавать его в `PodcastSubscriber` при создании, и закрывать в конце `main` (можно через тот же `try-with-resources`).

Еще я бы убрал `private static StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();`. Вы все равно клеите строку плюсами (это нормально), но ваш `stringBuilder` накапливает все строки, и вы каждый раз выводите все накопленные строки в поток.

Comment: спасибо. Проблема решена!